# Adjusting the format of numbers in the legend in ggplot2 or ggplotly

Tags: r, ggplot2, plotly

Please help,
I am trying to adjust the number which is shown when you hoover info on the geom_sf map that is converted to plotly object via ggplotly. For now, the number is shown without a comma or dot for thousand separators: e.g. the numbers are now shown like this: 15922784, and I would like it to be on the graph like this: 151,922,784 or 151.922.784. The picture of the current situation is here:

[image]

The number for variable "Ukupna_vrije..." is a number without dots or comma.
I tried to use forrmatable::scales with this code:

```
K1<-ggplot(data = spojeno) +
 geom_sf(aes(fill=formattable::comma(Ukupna_vrijednost_projekata), label=Županija))+
theme(panel.background = element_rect(fill = "white"), axis.line=element_blank(), 
axis.text.x=element_blank(), axis.text.y=element_blank(), axis.ticks=element_blank(), 
axis.title.x=element_blank(), axis.title.y=element_blank())+ 
scale_fill_viridis_c(option = "plasma")

ggplotly(K1)
```

then I do get the numbers with comma, but end up with "formatable::comma" literlly written on the map and legend, the picture and the code is below:

[image]

If I use scales::comma (instead of formmatable) then I get error message: Error: Discrete value supplied to continuous scale.
I suppose that I am putting this arguments on the wrong place or in worng format.

Also, I would like to add commas or dots to the numbers on the legend 3000000000, 2000000000 to have 3.000.000.000. Thanks.

Comment: Instead of formatting the variable, try with formatting the labels, i.e. try with `scale_fill_viridis_c(..., labels = scales::label_comma())`

Comment: Thank you stefan. This does solve the format of the numbers on the legend. I manage to control the appearance of the numbers on the map with text= argument. Here is the code if someone will have similar question:
    text = paste0("Županija: ",  Županija, "</b>", "<br>",
    "Ukupna vrijednost projekata: ", scales::comma(Ukupna_vrijednost_projekata, 1), "<br>"
  )))+ ...etc.. 
ggplotly(K1, tooltip = c("text"))

Comment: Haha. Great you figured it out yourself. Just added it an answer. (:

Answer (score 0):

As I already mentioned in my comment you could format the numbers in the legend via the `labels` argument of `scale_fill_xxx`. For the tooltip you could make use of the `text` aesthetic to style the tooltip. To display the content of `text` in the tooltip you have to call `ggplotly` with argument `tooltip="text"`.

Making use of the default example from `ggplot2::geom_sf`:

```r
library(plotly)

nc <- sf::st_read(system.file("shape/nc.shp", package = "sf"), quiet = TRUE)
nc$AREA <- nc$AREA * 1e6

ggplot(nc) +
  geom_sf(aes(fill = AREA, text = paste0("Name: ", NAME, "<br>", "Area: ", scales::comma(AREA)))) +
  scale_fill_viridis_c(option = "plasma", labels = scales::label_comma())

ggplotly(tooltip = "text")
```

[image]